# pyspark to pandas dataframe - type conversion

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Below is the pyspark code that will extract the data the hadoop cluster, where we have EMP table and we read the data from this table and we got the rows somewhere around 35 million rows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

query=f'''
with trans as (
    SELECT
        a.employee_name,
        a.employee_id

    FROM EMP
'''

employeeDF = spark.sql(query)

result_pdf = employeeDF.select("*").toPandas()
```

Now the problem here is the EMP table has 35 millionrows, so while extracting the data, we are using spark.sql function, which will call the above query, after the extract from EMP, the data will be in pyspark dataframe format.

then i am trying to convert that pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe using the toPandas() function. as we have to convert for further processing.

But then this conversion takens hours of processing time.

looking forward for the better solution, please suggest. thanks in Advance.

Comment: Whats stopping you to do the further processing using pyspark?

Comment: Spark in general is more suited to handling large datasets due to its distributed design, if you have no real need for a pandas DataFrame I would stick with a pyspark Dataframe. You are welcome to share your original task and we could help find a solution using pyspark.

Comment: @Vaebhav processing of converting pyspark df to pandas df is big issue and its time consuming, and creating alot of memory issues on the cluster.

Comment: @OfekGlick - we need to convert the pyspark df to pandas df, because the below processing paragraph are in python. But then converting df is the time consuming and a costly task related to processing and memory issues.